# Core Data errors in iPhone app. "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchedResultsController"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchedResultsController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-NSFetchedResultsController in RootViewController.o

I'm getting 7 of the errors above in my iphone app. I had an app that used core data but i wanted to use an rss xml parser with it, so i created a new empty app and put both of the projects into it, now i have 7 errors all the same as above!? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added the CoreData Framework to your project.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x5d030c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

Comment: Any ideas why that would cause the app to crash on start up?

Comment: Separate question. But you have unconnected outlets in IB, or you're trying to do something with a model class that has an attribute that's not in your .xcodemodel.